# VideoStabilizationSupport in iOS using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, video-capture

I am using AVFoundation to record video in my iOS app. Everything is working correctly. I am trying to enable video stabilization while recording video. Here is my code

I have AVCaptureConnetion as

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection;
```

Code to enable video stabilization when available

```
self.videoConnection = [self.videoOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

if([self.videoConnection isVideoMirroringSupported] && self.videoDeviceType == VideoDeviceTypeFrontCamera)
{
    [self.videoConnection setVideoMirrored:YES];
    NSLog(@"Video mirroring supported");
}
else
    NSLog(@"Video Mirroring not supported");

if ([self.videoConnection isVideoStabilizationSupported])
{
    [self.videoConnection enablesVideoStabilizationWhenAvailable];
    NSLog(@"Video Stabilization supported");
}
else
    NSLog(@"!!! Video Stabilization NOT supported");
```

Everytime I run the code , I am getting below output in Xcode console

`Video mirroring supported
!!! Video Stabilization NOT supported`

Why I am getting Video Stabilization NOT supported everytime ? I checked on iOS 6 & 7 with iPod touch 5G , iPad 2, iPad Mini.

According to [AppleDocs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureConnection/enablesVideoStabilizationWhenAvailable) , `Even so, not all source formats and video resolutions are supported.`

In my app , recorded video resoultion is 640*480 & mp4 format. Is this causing the issue ? If yes, what are the supported resolution & formats ? AppleDocs does not provide list of supported resolutions& formats.

Can anyone tell me about this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 640x480 does not support stabilization. Check out session 520 from WWDC 2012 ("What it new in camera capture").